# Unexpected port number using Indy10 idSMTP (Delphi / C++ Builder)

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy10

Trying to send mail with `Indy10`, but it seems to want to use port `465` instead of port `25`. I've tested it on various SMTP servers that allow port 25, but I only get the message:

> Cannot connect to SMTP server (62.149.128.11:**465**), connect error 10060.

Here is my simple code:

```
idSMTP1->Host = "smtp.xxyy.com";
idSMTP1->Username = "myname@xxyy.com";
idSMTP1->Password = "mypassword";
idSMTP1->Port = 25;
idSMTP1->AuthType = satDefault;
idSMTP1->UseTLS = utNoTLSSupport;
try {
  idSMTP1->Connect();
  }
catch(...) {
  throw;
  }
```

Comment: Try moving `idSMTP1->Port = 25;` beneath `idSMTP1->UseTLS = utNoTLSSupport;`

Comment: I tried to do it, but the problem remains the same: Cannot connect to SMTP server (62.149.128.11:465), connect error 10060.

Comment: Port 465 is the unofficial TLS port, so it is negiotiating TLS.
Are you using a specific IOHandler?
Make a WireShark Trace, maybe the remote end is asking for TLS?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem using the current public release of Indy 10.  The `Port` property remains set to `25` as expected when `Connect()` is called.

Comment: By chance, is the `TIdIOHandler::Destination` property being set after the `Port` property has been set?  That would override the `Port` setting. `TIdTCPClient` does have its own `Destination` property that gets assigned to the `TIdIOHandler::Destination` property by `Connect()` (personally, I don't see why `Destination` even exists, it is not used by anything in Indy).

Comment: @Remy, I discovered that the exe runs normally in another pc with port 25. The source of problem is outside of Indy10; perhaps the VMWare Windows configuration (it runs as VM under OSX). FTR the problem happens also with windows firewall down and Outlook express, too. Sorry for the bad request, thank you anyway!